# updating sql row where condition1,condition2 in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql, query

I have a non Eav Table and I want to update an attribute in a row where param1=a and param2=b.
In sql terms :
**update mytable column=ab where column1=a and column2=b;**
I have tried this way:

```
$mymodel=Mage::getModel(test/test)->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('column1',array('eq'=>'a')
->addAttributeToFilter('column2',array('eq'=>'b');
$var=(int)$mymodel->getData('column');
$var=+1;
```

Uptil here i am able to get my desired column and make change here

```
$mymodel=setColumn($var)->save();
```

but by using this i am unable to save the value back in db. Can anyone point me where I am doing wrong?What are the alternative ways to execute this query?

EDIT:
Another problem I am facing is in my getData line it's showing me the value 1
instead of value 5 which is stored in my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow code

```
$collection =Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('column1',array('eq'=>'a')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('column2',array('eq'=>'b');

foreach($collection as $test) {
    $test->setColumn1('123');
    $test->setcolumn2('345');
    $test->setId($test->getId());
    $test->save();
    //or 
    $test->setData(array('column1' => '123', 'column2' => '345'));
    $test->setId($test->getId());
    $test->save();
}
```